# Can the scrollviewer be used to stretch its contents horizontally between minwidth and maxwidth?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, scrollviewer, gridcontrol

I have a control which contains a devexpress `GridControl`.  I'd like to have a `ScrollViewer` set up so that when the viewing area is smaller than the minwidth of the `GridControl`, a horizontal scrollbar will appear.  Then as the viewing area is resized, I'd like the scrollbar to disappear when the viewing area is larger than the `MinWidth` and the `GridControl` to stretch with the window until `MaxWidth` is reached at which point the `GridControl` stops growing.  Then, and this is the part that seems so elusive, I'd like to be able to shrink the viewing area again and have the `GridControl` contract with it until 'MinWidth` is reached and the scrollbar reappears.

So far, I'm only able to achieve the `GridControl` growing - when the viewing area shrinks the scrollbar appears immediately and the `GridControl` will never get smaller.

Any ideas?

Edit:  This appears to be an issue with the DevExpress `GridControl`.  Here's an example that demonstrates the behavior with `Rectangle`s, a `DataGrid` and a `GridControl`:

```
<UserControl xmlns:dxg="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Xpf.Grid;assembly=DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v11.2"  x:Class="MyNamespace.ScrollViewerTest"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Width="500" Height="200" Fill="AliceBlue" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="200" MaxHeight="400" MinWidth="500" MaxWidth="1000" Fill="Bisque" />
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" MinWidth="500" MaxWidth="10000" MinHeight="200" MaxHeight="400">                
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Width="Auto"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Width="Auto"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" Width="Auto"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 4" Width="Auto"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="3" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="200" MaxWidth="1000" MaxHeight="400"/>
        </Grid>

    </ScrollViewer>        

</UserControl>
```

Notice how the `GridControl` starts out at `MaxWidth` and doesn't stretch with the rest of the controls.  Also, notice that the vertical resizing works - `GridControl` sizes up and down as you resize the window (you may have to adjust the `MinHeight`s if you have a smaller monitor).  The other controls resize correctly between max and min.  The first rectangle is of fixed width and height as a base case.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me (I substituted a ListBox rather than getting the GridControl):

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox Name="listBox1" MinWidth="400" MaxWidth="600" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I updated my question to include an example of the behavior, which seems to be related to the devexpress control.  I also included devexpress as a tag to be more specific.